# Регулярное выражение которое берет текст до определенного слова?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Какое регулярное выражение будет брать весть текст и все символы табуляции до определенного слова, например до слова "Малибу"?

Comment: _весть текст и все символы табуляции_ - почему это разделено?
 Символы табуляции не являются текстом?

Comment: А не проще найти индекс вхождения этого слова и взять всю строку сначала до найденного индекса? Будет быстрее и проще, к тому же регулярки под такую задачу не подходят.

Comment: ну я собсна пока так и сделал, но хотелось понять как это регуляркой сделать просто. надежнее ведь.

Comment: В данном случае - мысль неудачная. Не для этого они.

Comment: Я всецело согласен с вашей фразой, явно проблема XY, но это не ответ, а лишь комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пожелает автор через регулярки (брать первое совпадение):

```
.+?(?=Малибу)
```

- Выражение `.+?` - берет все символы (`.` - все символы) до первого совпадения (`+?` - "ленивый" отбор);
- Выражение `(?=...)` называется [`Positive lookahead`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) и берет совпадения по
  выражению (`.+?` у нас), которое находится **до** выражения внутри
  (`Малибу` в нашем случае).

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XP7IxQ)!

Но, как сказал @Сергей, этот путь далеко не оптимальный для такой тривиальной задачи.

Comment: Как это работает?) Сначала все что угодно, а потом как это расшифровывается(два вопроса)?

Comment: @kot_mapku3 обновил ответ.